# Pyspark - Failed to get main class in JAR with error 'File file:/home/xpto/spark/, does not exist'

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

Im using pyspark to write into kafka.

When I run the command:

```
bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly_2.12:3.0.1,org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.0.2 --jars /home/xpto/spark/jars/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly_2.12-3.0.1.jar , /home/xpto/spark/jars/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.0.2.jar , /home/xpto/spark/jars/kafka-clients-2.6.0.jar --verbose  --master local[2] /home/xavy/Documents/PersonalProjects/Covid19Analysis/pyspark_job_to_write_data_to_kafkatopic.py
```

Im receiving an error:

```
:: retrieving :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-ad9bf9ab-6d6d-4edd-bd1f-4b3145c2457f
    confs: [default]
    0 artifacts copied, 7 already retrieved (0kB/3ms)
20/11/22 18:35:02 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get main class in JAR with error 'File file:/home/xpto/spark/, does not exist'.  Please specify one with --class.
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.error(SparkSubmit.scala:936)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:457)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1007)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1016)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I dont know which class the spark is asking for...

Im running this locally in my pc, not sure if is the right way to do it.

Can someone help and point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

So, spacing matters - make sure you don't put spaces in your file paths

For example, you've put this path in your packages line

```
, /home/xpto/spark/jars/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.0.2.jar
```

Not clear why you give a local file path when getting them from maven should work fine. However, you need to use consistent Spark versions... You've mixed 3.x and 2.x as well as Scala 2.12 and 2.11

You also shouldn't don't need both spark-streaming-kafka and spark-sql-kafka

---

Regarding the error, the syntax that it thinks you've tried to use is for Java

```
spark-submit [options]  --class MainClass application.jar
```

For python applications, you might want to use `--py-files`